# Plotting shapes where condition is met first, but not on consecutive candles?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write an indicator which produces multiple true conditions for shapes plotted. For example, a MACD cross combined with an ADX condition which looks something like this:

```
study("MACD on chart", shorttitle="MACD on Chart", overlay=true)

// MACD
// Inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=6)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=13)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 4)
sma_source = input(title="Simple MA(Oscillator)", type=input.bool, defval=false)
sma_signal = input(title="Simple MA(Signal Line)", type=input.bool, defval=false)
// Calculation
fast_ma = sma_source ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
// hist = macd - signal

// DMI
// Inputs
lensig = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
// Calculation
up = change(high)
down = -change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = rma(tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)


longCondition = macd >= signal and adx >= 20
plotshape(longCondition, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 60), location=location.belowbar)

shortCondition = signal <= macd and adx >= 20
plotshape(shortCondition, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 60), location=location.abovebar)
```

Unfortunately this produces multiple plotted shapes on the chart, because the condition is true for, well, multiple candles. Instead it would like to have only the first occurrence where the new condition is met anew have a shape.

To prevent one question: No, I can't use `crossover` in this case, because the way I use it in the script produces wrong results. The crossover is only true on the candle it actually crosses over, but the condition is set up in a way, that the actual crossover wouldn't be the right trigger candle. I hope that makes sense.

Here's a visual example:

[image]

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you mean you want to have exactly one shape over the entire chart? Meaning, only draw the shape on the first time the condition is met, but never again after that first occurance? Even if the condition becomes true again after that first occurance? Could you maybe update your question with an annotated screenshot of what you're looking for? And if possible, also the entire script that you have so far, so that we can evaluate it? Thanks.

Comment: Of course not. Only the first time, the condition is met again in a series. I just don't want to have it multiple times in a row, and then when the condition is met again, then again only one plot.

Comment: Could you please post a script that shows what you mean? And also the ticker + timeframe it occurs on. I'm sure I can solve this for you.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I try to get a minimal example ready for you. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: I've changed the question to make it better understandable and added also a chart, which should help explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you're looking for.
I see that you're calculating [macd](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_macd) and [dmi](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_dmi), which also exist as built-in functions.
You can find many more in the [Pine Script Language Reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/).
Also, you don't need to create a `color.new()` to get a transparancy in `plotshape()`, because it's available as a parameter.

```
//@version=4
study("MACD on chart", shorttitle="MACD on Chart", overlay=true)

var bool longCondition          = na
var bool shortCondition         = na
var bool showLong               = na
var bool showShort              = na
var bool showOnlyFirstSignal    = input(true, "Show only first signal", input.bool)

// MACD
// Inputs
fast_length     = input(title="Fast Length",            type=input.integer, defval=6)
slow_length     = input(title="Slow Length",            type=input.integer, defval=13)
src             = input(title="Source",                 type=input.source,  defval=close)
signal_length   = input(title="Signal Smoothing",       type=input.integer, defval= 4, minval = 1, maxval = 50)
sma_source      = input(title="Simple MA(Oscillator)",  type=input.bool,    defval=false)
sma_signal      = input(title="Simple MA(Signal Line)", type=input.bool,    defval=false)

// Calculation
fast_ma         = sma_source ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma         = sma_source ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd            = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal          = sma_signal ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
// hist = macd - signal

// DMI
// Inputs
lensig          = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len             = input(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
// Calculation
up              = change(high)
down            = -change(low)
plusDM          = na(up)   ? na : (up > down and up > 0   ? up   : 0)
minusDM         = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur            = rma(tr, len)
plus            = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM,  len) / trur)
minus           = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum             = plus + minus
adx             = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)

longCondition   := macd >= signal and adx >= 20
shortCondition  := signal <= macd and adx >= 20

showLong        := showOnlyFirstSignal ? longCondition  and not longCondition[1]  : longCondition
showShort       := showOnlyFirstSignal ? shortCondition and not shortCondition[1] : shortCondition

plotshape(showLong,  style=shape.labelup,   size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=60, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(showShort, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red,   transp=60, location=location.abovebar)
```

Edit: Extra explanation as requested in comments.

Short version

```
showLong := showOnlyFirstSignal ? longCondition and not longCondition[1] : longCondition
```

Long version

```
if showOnlyFirstSignal
    // To show Long on the chart, the longCondition on the current bar must be true, but the longCondition on the previous bar must be false.
    // So, as long as the longCondition on the previous bar stays true, showLong will be false, resulting in it not showing on the chart.
    // The reverse is also true: showLong can only become true, if the longCondition on the previous bar was false.
    showLong    := longCondition and not longCondition[1]
else
    showLong    := longCondition
```

You might also want to take a look at the [ternary conditional operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D), which may clear things up further for you.

Comment: Oh wow. That makes a lot of sense actually. Thank you Bjorn. Can you explain to me what `longCondition and not longCondition[1]  : longCondition` does? I understand it like a short form of an if condition. So showLong is true if longCondition is true but not 1 bar back, else it's just the longCondition. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Updated my answer to explain what you asked. Previous values in Pine are referenced with `[n]` where `n` stands for the number of bars back from the current bar.

Comment: Bjorn, that is a monster answer. I did not expect this much help. Thank you very much. :)